# How to change font style all over the device in windows 10 mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, settings, nokia-lumia-535, personalization

I have lumia 535 running Windows 10 mobile(official upgrade). Is there any way to change the font style of my device? I can't find such option in settings or in search results. I read an article here: http://winphonehub.org/interop-how-to-change-system-fonts-on-windows-10-mobile/ that says it's possible but that all gone over my head. So I was thinking as if it were possible via some other way or if it is the only way is there any explanation to all those steps? My phone is  dual sim Lumia 535 (RM-1090) running W10M (14393.693) if relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no official way to change the default font for the OS. You'll need registry access to do that which requires an interop unlock as the article you've linked to states.

Comment: Please @Thomas visit the link in question there is a way but it was a very hard way So I didn't go through it.

Comment: Yup.........I did this by registry access